# Get the two team info in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a team table with columns: team_id,team_name, logo.
I have a schedule table with columns: schedule_id,home_team, guest_team, the_day, the_time.
home_team and guest_team are team_id in the team table.
I want to query the schedule table and get the information of home_team and guest_team in a query, how do I write?

[team table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzLwA.jpg)
[schedule table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2azLA.jpg)

Comment: Please include some sample data.  Your question is a bit thin.

Comment: I took a demo image for the question

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT schedule.*, a.team_name AS home_team, b.team_name AS guest_team
FROM schedule
LEFT JOIN team AS a ON a.team_id=home_team
LEFT JOIN team AS b ON b.team_id=guest_team
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want

```
select s.schedule_id, a.team_name, b.team_name, s.the_day,s.the_time
from schedule s
left join team as a on a.team_id=home_team
left join team as b on b.team_id=guest_team
```

or hardcoded version with case statement:

```
select s.schedule_id, 
CASE WHEN home_team = '1' THEN 'manchester united' WHEN home_team = '2' THEN 'manchester city' WHEN home_team = '3' THEN 'chelsea' WHEN home_team = '4' then 'arsenal' END as 'Home Team', 
CASE WHEN guest_team = '1' THEN 'manchester united' WHEN guest_team = '2' THEN 'manchester city' WHEN guest_team = '3' THEN 'chelsea' WHEN guest_team = '4' then 'arsenal' END as 'Guest Team',
s.the_day,s.the_time
from schedule s
```

Comment: Your second query returns full data but in practice it can not be written so because the data will be more than the demo.

Comment: I corrected the query and it gave full data. Thank you for supporting me.